# Add custom message based on product tag in WooCommerce email notification

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, tags, product, email-notifications

I want to add unique text to WooCommerce's "order complete" email but ONLY when the product purchased has a certain product tag.

If the item purchased has the "fundraiser" tag I want the email to include text thanking them for supporting our fundraisers.  Long story but we can't use categories for this and we must use tags.

I've tried editing the customer-complete-order.php file and this works, however I'm not good with PHP code and there are no examples of how to call the tags.

I've also tried editing functions.php based upon what someone else did and this is as far as I've gotten.

```php
function woocommerce_custom_email_per_product_depending_on_product_tag( $email_heading, $order ) {
global $woocommerce;
$items = $order->get_items();
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $product_tag = $item['product_tag'];
    if ( $product_tag == fundraiser ) {
        $email_body = 'Thanks for buying a fundraiser.';
    }
    return $email_heading;
}   }
```

or perhaps it would be better to define this custom text in a new email template?  Here's the order confirmation template as woocommerce provides it.

```php
<?php
/**
 * Customer completed order email
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/customer-completed-order.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
 * @version 3.5.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_header() Output the email header
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

<?php /* translators: %s: Customer first name */ ?>
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Hi %s,', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $order->get_billing_first_name() ) ); ?></p>
<?php /* translators: %s: Site title */ ?>
<p><?php esc_html_e( 'We have finished processing your order.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
<?php

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_details() Shows the order details table.
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_order_data() Generates structured data.
 * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::output_structured_data() Outputs structured data.
 * @since 2.5.0
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_meta() Shows order meta data.
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::customer_details() Shows customer details
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_address() Shows email address
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

?>
<p>
<?php esc_html_e( 'Thanks for shopping with us.', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
</p>
<?php

/*
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_footer() Output the email footer
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- No need to overwrite template files, you can use the `woocommerce_email_before_order_table` hook
- Via `$email->id` you can target the desired email

So you get:

```php
function woocommerce_custom_email_per_product_depending_on_product_tag( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    $items = $order->get_items();
    
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {               
        // get an array of the WP_Term objects for a defined product ID
        $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $item['product_id'], 'product_tag' );
        
        foreach($terms as $term){
            $term_names[] = $term->name; // Product tag Name
            
            //$term->term_id; Product tag Id
            //$term->slug; Product tag slug
        }
    }
    
    if ( $email->id == 'customer_processing_order' && in_array('Fundraiser', $term_names) ) {
        echo 'Thanks for buying a fundraiser.';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'woocommerce_custom_email_per_product_depending_on_product_tag', 10, 4 );
```